# I want to clean a nested dictionary python using dictionary comprehension or for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a nested dictionary which contains a series of keys Dictionary_ABC = {'ABC 1':..., 'ABC 2': ..., ..., 'ABC N':...}. Each of these keys contains random values not associate with the ABC keys, but also others that are. For example:

```
Dictionary_ABC['ABC 1'] = {'ABC 1': {'ZYZZ': NONE, 'DAFDZ': NONE, 'EASDF': NONE, 'ABC 1': NONE, ..., 'ABC N': NONE}}
```

In the sub dictionary 'ABC 1', I would like to delete all ABC values which do not contain 'ABC 1'. So the end result should be something like this:

```
Dictionary_ABC['ABC 1'] = {'ABC 1': {'ZYZZ': NONE, 'DAFDZ': NONE, 'EASDF': NONE, 'ABC 1': NONE}}
```

All of the other ABC #'s should fall off and I am just left with the other subkeys and the one that matches the primary key.

I've tried many different solutions, but the one that seems to produce the closest result is:

```
Dictionary_ABC_Copy = {}
for key in Dictionary_ABC:
   for subkey in Dictionary_ABC[key]:
       if this criteria met:
           if this next criteria met:
                pass #I don't want to copy this
           else:
                Dictionary_ABC_Copy[key] = subkey #copy if it doesn't fit both criteria
        else:
            Dictionary_ABC_Copy[key] = subkey #because I want to copy this
```

The criteria are producing the necessary result, however whenever I attempt to update the dictionary or use the method above, the dictionary overwrites all the previous values. I would simply like to update keys with these values if they don't pass to the filter criteria. This is my first question.

My second question is there a better way to do this? I hope that I have provided the material the information necessary to help answer these questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
dictionary_abc_copy = {
   abc: {k: v for k, v in inner.items() if not k.startwith('ABC ') or k == abc}
   for abc, inner in dictionary_abc.items()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Elazar I was able to get this to work with a little bit of modification. Thank you very much for this I appreciate this.

Comment: What was the modification?

Comment: I neglected to mention that there was one dictionary value that did not contain ABC and a #, this one I need to be in every key. So I modified it to account for this using: k.startswith('ABC ') and re.findall(r'\d+', str(k)) or if re.findall(r'ABC \d+', str(k)) == re.findall(r'ABC \d+', str(abc)). This produced the necessary results including having ABC w/o in each subdictionary. For some reason using k == abc did not work for me. Perhaps it was a configuration problem. But re.findall was able to solve this problem.

Comment: Okay. If the answer solves your question, then please mark as accepted.